# Alternatives to TabHost and TabSpec to detect onClick

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, onclicklistener, android-4.3-jelly-bean

On an Android app (sdk min 11, target 18), as a main navigation widget I used TabHost with 4 items (TabSpec).
My app needs to be able to detect whenever an item is clicked - **even if the very same item is clicked twice**. OnTabChangeListener is not suitable for this scenario and I noticed, with my surprise, that neither TabHost nor TabSpec have an onClick listener.

1. Am I using the wrong widget to detect this sort of events?
2. Any alternatives?

Comment: 1. It's not about not using the proper widget, the question is why do you want to get that event. If you're using this same selection event to refresh the data maybe you should reconsider your approach and add a refresh menu item in the ActionBar(especially if every tab will have this behavior). 2. You make your own `TabHost` which has a listener that gets triggered for selections of the same tab(but setting an onClick is much easier).

Comment: From a navigation point of view, I'd like to assign to each tab button the behaviour of deleting all views from the stack and display the root view associated to the clicked button. I'm happy to create my own TabHost. Should I use onTouch and work out what tab was touched based on the coords?

Comment: *deleting all views from the stack and display the root view associated to the clicked button.* - what exactly does this mean? What do you have in those tabs?

Comment: Let's say my TabBar has 4 buttons: A,B,C,D. When I click on button A, root view A1 is displayed. From A1 I can then navigate to other views A2 and A3. I want the user to be able to return to root view A1 whenever button A is clicked, without having to use the back button.

Comment: I would simply use a `OnClickListener` for what you want to do, it's much easier.